# Angular2 - Run function from child component in parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I'am working on ng2 RC6. I have parent component, and child component.

Inside child component I got ng2-bootstrap modal, and start function:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'nba-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html'
})


export class FormComponent {
    public modal:boolean = false;

    @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;
    @ViewChild('lgModal') public lgModal: ModalDirective;

    public showChildModal(): void {
        this.childModal.show();
    }

    public hideChildModal(): void {
        this.childModal.hide();
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.lgModal.show();
    }
}
```

In parent component I want to run function "this.lgModal.show()", which is opening modal window.

```
{...}
import { FormComponent } from './form.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Component({
    selector: 'nba',
    templateUrl: './nba.component.html',
    providers: [FormComponent]
})
export class NbaComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private appService: AppService, private formComponent: FormComponent) {}
```

But when I'am using:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formComponent.lgModal.show();
}
```

I got ERR that `show();` is undefined

And app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { AlertModule, DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryData } from './in-memory-data';

import { FormComponent } from './form.component';
import { NbaComponent } from './nba.component';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AlertModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DatepickerModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryData),
    ModalModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, NbaComponent, FormComponent],
  providers: [AppService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

PS. I can open modal from child component - this is work, but when I try do it from parent component, I have problem. Please for hint!:)

Regards,
Bosper

Comment: Could you try it in `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: I had tried, result is same: "Cannot read property 'show' of undefined" :(

Comment: Why is the `formComponent` a provider? Shouldn't it be in the `directives` array if it's a component and not be instantiated via DI in the constructor?

Comment: I can't move it into directives... When I doing that, compilator is yelling:
"'directives' does not exist in type 'ComponentMetadataType'". I think that was a change in new RC. Now I have app.module.ts, I'v edited post and added this code.

Comment: Oh, ok - sorry. I'm not following the TS development atm, since I switched to the Dart version.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding instance of child component in parent with annotation `@ViewChild()`, where I wannt run child function:

```
@ViewChild(FormComponent)
    private formComponent: FormComponent;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.formComponent.lgModal.show();
    }
```